# Как использовать переменную из одного скрипта в другом на разных обьектах

Tags: unity3d

```
    GameObject.Find("GameController").gameObject.GetCompo‌​nent<GameController>();
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("GameController");
    GameController gameController = go.GetComponent<GameController>();
```

Пробовал и нехрена не выходит.
Два разных скрипта и они на разных обьектах размещены.
Первый скрипт

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {    
public float HealthWall = 100;
```

Второй скрипт. Сюда передать значение.

```
public class II : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject GameController;
GameObject go = GameObject.Find("GameController");
GameController gameController = go.GetComponent<GameController>();
float courrentSpeed = GameController.HealthWall;
```

Ошибка:     CS1061  'GameObject" не содержит определения для "HealthWall" и не удалось найти метод расширения "HealthWall", принимающий тип "GameObject" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: Вот здесь вы правильно вызываете? `float courrentSpeed = GameController.HealthWall;` Должно быть может `float courrentSpeed = gameController.HealthWall;` ?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://answers.unity.com/questions/246211/having-scripts-interact.html)

Comment: @TimurVI, с большой или с маленькой ошибку по прежнему выводит. Сейчас гляну.

Comment: у вас HealthWall это функция принимающая аргумент типа GameObject, а вы вызываете, словно это свойство